# Problems to load teleriks report

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik-reporting

Thanks for reading my post.

I am working for some time on a C# Windows Form app with Teleriks Reports as a part of it.

It worked some time, and now when i try to test it, i only get this error on the teleriks report, trying to load it, create it or even create it from another new project:

```
    To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:   
    1 Error         
    Why am I seeing this page?      
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Instances of this error (1)

```
1.      Hide Call Stack
at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.GetModeField(ModeField field, Int16 defaultValue, IntPtr modeHandle)
at System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings.get_Landscape()
at Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PageSettings..ctor(PageSettings pageSettings, PrinterSettings printerSettings)
at Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PageSettings.GetPrinterPageSettings()
at Telerik.Reporting.Drawing.PageSettings.get_DefaultPageSettings()
at Telerik.Reporting.Report..ctor()
```

Help with this error
MSDN Help

Forum posts about this error
Search the MSDN Forums for posts related to this error

Comment: Do you have a default printer selected in your system?

Comment: Yes i do, i have a defaul printer

Comment: post the code that causes this exception please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the printer and solved this issue